# How to Avoid Skipping First Row in Pandas Data Frame (Python)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I used `df = pd.read_csv('text.csv', skiprows=1)` to skip the text headings in the data set. The output is similar to this:

```
  24424 5435 4343 
0 43533 3432 5346 
1 42243 4353 3434
```

However, what I want is:

```
0 24424 5435 4343 
1 43533 3432 5346 
2 42243 4353 3434
```

Because the first line currently won't print when I e.g. do this:

```
df2 = df.values.tolist()
print(df2)
```

Out:

```
[[43533 3432 5346], [42243 4353 3434]]
```

Where the first row is unfortunately skipped. Any ideas how to fix?

Note: I didn't use `headers=None` as suggested, otherwise I get this output:

```
0 colA  colB colC
1 24424 5435 4343 
2 43533 3432 5346 
3 42243 4353 3434
```

Comment: use headers=False

Comment: @ChristianSloper `headers=None` doesn't work because there are headers in the csv file, which will be used as the first row if I do this. That's why I used `skiprows=1` so that the headers aren't used in the output. Any ideas how to still achieve what I'm aiming for?

Comment: if there are headers, then don't use skiprows